Using sudo, why are detached child process terminated when the parent dies?
I'm writing a program that requires admin privileges (an updater). At some point, we need to start another program and let the first one end. So the parent process makes a fork, detaches from its child and ends execution.
As root (using "su" for exemple), everything works as expected.
As a regular user, nothing special happens (except of course for writing files as root).
But, using sudo, as soon as the parent process ends its execution, its child dies as well.
I wrote a minimal program to debug this issue:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "start: " << getuid() << std::endl;
    if (auto pid = fork() == 0)
    {
        setpgid(0, 0);
        std::cout << "fork has detached" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
        std::ofstream test("/root/test.txt");
        std::cout << "fork: " << getuid() << " " << test.is_open() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        setpgid(pid, 0);
        std::cout << "parent: " << getuid() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

I expect as output:
$ sudo ./test_sudo
start: 0
parent: 0
fork has detached
$ fork: 0 1

Note: the last line should be written after the prompt.
But with sudo I only get:
$ sudo ./test_sudo
start: 0
parent: 0
fork has detached
$

If I add a wait() call in the parent, the child works as expected with sudo. So the child dies with its parent. The debug tools I tried only showed traces for the parent, how can I track the detached child as well?
Why does using sudo makes my program behave this way?
I can work around this issue for my project, but I'm interested in the explanation of this strange behaviour.

On MacOS, the behavior is identical sudo or not. Last lines:
fork: 0 0 or fork: 501 0

strace --follow-forks will show traces for children too.  I'm guessing that's not one of the debug tools you used?

BTW, probably not the cause, but you probably meant if (auto pid = fork();  pid == 0) rather than making pid a bool.

This is a security feature. sudo allocates a new pseudoterminal before it executes the specified command. This is to avoid injection attacks from terminals that are not controlled by sudo directly, see for example this SuSE security advisory.
In your case this leads to a slight issue: your program is actually still running, but you won't see its output: if you change the final std::cout << ... in the child process with the following:
        std::ofstream log("/tmp/log");
        log << "fork: " << getuid() << " " << test.is_open() << std::endl;

you will see in /tmp/log that the program still executed. You just didn't get to see the output because sudo deallocated the pseudo-terminal once the parent process was done. So your std::cout write tried to write to a now-closed pty, which lead to the output being discarded. (std::cout.fail() would be true after the std::cout << ... line because the write did actually fail.)

@MaximeBeluguet The X11 part is more related to xauth than to the pseudo-terminal. But IMHO the easiest thing is to simply keep the program running while it still requires X11, and the user can always run the sudo command in the background if they don't want it to block their terminal.

This seems to be environment specific behavior.
I've tested on a Mac OS 12.7.4 zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0) and Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and every time last line is present.
$ sudo ./a.out 
start: 0
parent: 0
fork has detached
$ fork: 0 1

Note: the last line is delayed and printed after prompt.

A shell which does not attempt to restore the line might be called "simpler" or "minimalist" or maybe "smarter", but definitely not "dumber".

Yes, that is what I expect. I added the prompt in my question to clarifiy. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), and I can't get the last line with sudo.
Maybe this depends on some configuration setting.

The highest voted answer is obviously correct and is well explained. Do not mock mine, which had no clue.

When you run with sudo, sudo process becomes the session leader.
When the parent exits, sudo exits as well, thus causing all processes (including grand-children of sudo) of the session to teminate.

This contradicts with the fact, that all processes in example run to completion. Only output is lost.

@Basilevs Do you think that std::cout << "fork: "... has been run, only output is lost ?

yes. I think this might be proven by redirecting sudo output to a file. Sudo should be smart enough not to allocate a terminal then.

Also, see my answer, where older versions of sudo did not terminate anything by default.
